# Pyspark dataframe Inner Join Doesn't Work for a second time

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, join, pyspark, inner-join

I am trying to join a table with itself several times to get the cnt for all its connections:
original table:

```
cust_id    node_1    node_2    cnt    
----------------------------------
1          5         6         12
5          10        9         3
6          7         10        4
```

The table I wanted:

```
cust_id   cnt    cnt_node_1    cnt_node_2   
-----------------------------------------
1         12     3             4
```

(notice here that cnt_node_1 is the cnt value for cust_id 5 and it is 3, same for cnt_node_2)

I am able to join produce the result for the first node

```
cust_id   cnt    cnt_node_1  
----------------------------
1         12     3
```

by using code:

```
df1 = table.alias('df1')
df2 = table.select("cust_id", "cnt").withColumnRenamed("cust_id", "cust_id_1").withColumnRenamed("cnt", "cnt_1").alias('df2')
df1 = df1.join(df2, on = df1.node_1 == df2.cust_id_1, how = "inner")
```

Then I am trying to do the same thing for node 2, using the exact same code

```
df2 = table.select("cust_id", "cnt").withColumnRenamed("cust_id", "cust_id_2").withColumnRenamed("cnt", "cnt_2").alias('df2')
df1 = df1.join(df2, on = df1.node_2 == df2.cust_id_2, how = "inner")
```

but I got NULLs everywhere:

```
cust_id   cnt    cnt_node_1    cnt_node_2   
-----------------------------------------
1         12     3             NULL
```

Can someone give me a hint why this inner join does not work for the second time? Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple.

```
nn = 2 # nodes 
cols = ['node_1','node_2']
new_cols = [i+'_cnt' for i in cols]
df.reindex(columns=[*cv.columns.tolist(), *new_cols], fill_value=0)

for i in cols:
    df[i+'_cnt'] = df['cnt']-df['i']
```